# streamlit installation on anaconda navigator fails with "ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyarrow"

Tags: installation, anaconda, streamlit

I am trying to install streamlit in anaconda environment.

The error looks like this:

```
   RuntimeError: Not supported on 32-bit Windows
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyarrow
Failed to build pyarrow
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyarrow which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I have tried to update anaconda. Also to make new environments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Raise RuntimeError('Not supported on 32-bit Windows')" when installing pyarrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55834425/raise-runtimeerrornot-supported-on-32-bit-windows-when-installing-pyarrow)

Comment: Thank you!! I have now installed 64 bits and it worked!!